# Boundary of star-shaped domain

Tags: differential-topology

Assume that $M\subset R^n$, $n\ge 3$, is a boundary of an open bounded set $D$ containing $0$, which is starlike w.r.t. 0, meaning that each ray $[0,x]$ from $x\in M$ to $0$ meets $M$ only once. Is $M$ smooth almost everywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unit circle is a boundary of an open bounded set $D$ containing $\mathbf{0}$,

which is starlike w.r.t. $\mathbf{0}$, and which is smooth almost everywhere.

When $f$ is [the original Weierstrass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function#Construction), $\;\; \left\{\begin{bmatrix} \left(\frac{1+a}{1+(-a)}+f(\theta)\right) \cdot \cos(\pi \cdot \theta) \\ \left(\frac{1+a}{1+(-a)}+f(\theta)\right) \cdot \sin(\pi \cdot \theta) \end{bmatrix} \: : \: \theta \in [-1,1]\right\}$

is a boundary of an open bounded set $D$ containing $\mathbf{0}$, which

is starlike w.r.t. $\mathbf{0}$, and which is not smooth almost everywhere.

Comment: You should take $f$ to be positive (this can be arranged by adding a positive constant, it it needed). It is open because $D=\{z=re^{is}: r<f(s)\}$. 

Thanks.

Comment: Can you answer to the newer question?

Comment: @Malota: Why can't you just increase the dimension of Ricky Demer's Weierstrass-function example by taking the product of his $D$ with the cube `$(-1,1)^{n-2}$` (and increase the dimension of his round example by using an $n$-dimensional ball)?